# What does it mean when "mean" is equal to one of the data points and the variance is extremely huge

Tags: r

I have the following data points:

```
1097.492, 3988.262, 14493.27, 52668.23, 191395.3, 695526.7, 2527530, 498099.9
```

Mean of these 8 numbers is equal to the last number, i.e. 498099.9

Can this mean anything or tell anything about my data?

Furthermore, the variance is extremely huge (i.e. 739296290484), how about this? Can this lead to any conclusions about the data?

Comment: There's some obvious things to be said here. First -- where do these numbers come from?

Comment: These numbers come from the growth rate (`r`) of a particular cell line at different time intervals in a Malthusian growth model used in solving a bioinformatics problem while modelling the drug response to a cancer treatment. The growth rates of all other 9 cell lines that I have also behave in the same way (i.e. mean for their growth rates is equal to the last number).

Comment: Note that there's no variation in the numbers you gave - each one is  3.63398 times the previous one, apart from the mean at the end. 1. These values are not growth rates. 2. Are you sure someone didn't just give the mean at the end of the list?  3. Why would it make any sense to calculate the mean and variance of values that clearly come from different distributions? What could that tell you?

Answer (score 2):

You could look at `summary()` (and/or at boxplot/densityplot/...) of your data, which should give you a feeling about what you are dealing with:

```
d <- c(1097.492, 3988.262, 14493.27, 52668.23, 191395.3, 695526.7, 2527530, 498099.9)
summary(d)
#   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   1097   11870  122000  498100  547500 2528000 
boxplot(d)
```

[image: Boxplot]

You can compare what you see in this with your domain specific knowledge (about what you assume the feature/data *should* look like, if you have such information at all). If I would have e.g. many many samples and only one "outlier", such as the one in the boxplot above (which needs not be an outlier, but could be one), I would maybe think about how this could have happened, and if it could make *sense* to have such a sample. But besides this, just having a certain tiny or huge mean, median, sd, mad, or similar, does not yet indicate anything problematic or strange. You will likely normalizing your data (center, scale) before handing it to any models anyway - so just having huge/tiny numbers won't change much here.

One more thing: the fact that the last value is *exactly equal* to your mean could be coincidence - but if you are dealing with a larger portion of data (e.g. multiple such samples), double check that this is not just a "mean" column somebody has added before, but not labeled as such (such things happen...).